# WCF Service Creation

Tags: wcf

I am trying to build a small WCF service and wanted to utilize it in a test application.

**PFB service code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace HelloIndigo
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.thatindigoirl.com/samples/2006/06")]
    public interface IHelloIndigoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string HelloIndigo();
    }
    public class HelloIndigoService : IHelloIndigoService
    {
        public string HelloIndigo()
        {
            return "Hello indigo";
        }
    }
}
```

**Host Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Host
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloIndigo.HelloIndigoService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/HelloIndigo")))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HelloIndigo.IHelloIndigoService), new BasicHttpBinding(), @"HelloIndigoService");
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service hosy");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I am trying to run Host I am getting below mentioned error in host.Open() statement.

> HTTP could not register URL
>   http://+:8000/HelloIndigo/. Your
>   process does not have access rights to
>   this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353
>   for details).

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The most important parts - the **configs** for the server and client side - are missing. Without those, we can only guess.....

Comment: Have you clicked on the Microsoft link in the error message? It explains what it is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the host app with elevated privileges (i.e., "As Administrator"). Under Vista/Win7, only administrative accounts have the permission to register socket listeners.

Comment: @ServiceGuys: Thanks a lot. Its done.. I almost forgot to do that after switching from XP to Win7

Comment: Done.. Sorry I missed it first place:)